# Finding index of a firestore document for a given query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore to build a game and I'd like to show a list of high scores.

I'm currently getting the 10 highest scores with the following query:

```js
const q = query(doc(db, "scores", title), orderBy("score", "desc"), limit(10));
```

In addition to this, I'd like to let the player know how they fared compared to global high scores. For example, if they got the 956th-highest score, I'd like them to know their relative position is 956.

I've seen that, for [cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), one can provide an offset with a given document, ie:

```js
const q = query(doc(db, "scores", title), orderBy("score", "desc"), limit(10), startAt(myScoreDocRef));
```

Is there any way from this to get the score's logical index in the sorted result set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore recently added [`getCountFromServer()`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_9110_-_october_06_2022) ([API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getcountfromserver)) function that is perfect for this use case. You can create a query that matches documents with score greater than current user's score and fetch the count as shown below:

```
const currentUserScore = 24;

const q = query(
  collection(db, 'users'),
  orderBy('score', 'desc'),
  where('score', '>', currentUserScore)
)

// number of users with higher score
const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(q)
console.log(`Your rank: ${snapshot.data().count + 1}`)
```

However, in case multiple users have same score, they will all see same rank with this query. As a workaround you can add another parameter to the ranking apart from score, like querying users with same score and checking user age or so.

The count query costs only 1 read for each batch of up to 1000 index entries matched by the query (as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#aggregation_queries)) so it's much for efficient than querying users with some offset and manually calculating the rank.

Comment: As an additional note, as `getCountFromServer()` was only added about two weeks ago, make sure to update your firebase library version to 9.11.0 or higher.